# Variable assignment in recursion

Tags: prolog

Given this:

```
useAdd(List, What) :-                                         
    addToList(List, What, New),                               
    reverseList(New, T),                                      
    write("done "),                                           
    write(T), nl, !.                                          

addToList(List, What, [ What | List]).                        

reverseList([], List) :- write(List), nl.                     
reverseList([H | Old], []) :- reverseList(Old, [ H ]).        
reverseList([ H | Old], New) :- reverseList(Old, [ H | New]).
```

Why does this happen (in swipl)?

```
?- useAdd([42, 100, ok], hello).
[ok,100,42,hello]
done []
true.
```

Obviously assigning to `New` in `useAdd` amounted to something, because the correct list is passed to `reverseList`.  But then, unlike `New`, `T` in `useAdd` is empty.

- How are those two assignments different?  Why does one work and the other not?
- How can I get the reversed list into `T` in `useAdd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `reverseList/2` *uses* `T` as the reversed list's tail.  The reversed list is built and printed at the deepest level of recursion, and then nothing is done with that created value:

```
2 ?- reverseList( [1,2,3,4], [0]).
[4,3,2,1,0]
true.
```

Instead, pass it in as a fresh logical variable, as a third parameter, pass it along unchanged between the invocations, and finally set it at the deepest level:

```
reverseList([], List, T) :- List = T, write(List), nl. 
reverseList([H | Old], [], T) :- reverseList(Old, [ H ], T).
reverseList([ H | Old], New, T) :- reverseList(Old, [ H | New], T).
```

Then call it as `reverseList( [1,2,3,4], Newtail, T)` to get your `T` set at the deepest level of recursion:

```
6 ?- reverseList( [1,2,3,4], [0], T).
[4,3,2,1,0]
T = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0].
```

The definition is all over the place, the naming is terrible, and it used `T` probably for "tail", so you should name the new argument something like `R` instead, to at least hint at the fact that it will hold the *reversed* list as the *result* of an invocation.

Comment: Actually T was for tmp.  That code isn't in use anywhere, which is why it looks half-baked; it's an exasperated SSCCE. I've just started studying prolog for school.  You'd think I'd be able to recognize issues with recursion like this by now though...when something is new to you always blame the compiler ;)